# Why has_f in Stroustup book does not work?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

struct Y {
void f(int i) {}
 };

 template<bool B,typename T=void>
 using Enable_if = typename std::enable_if<B, T>::type;

 struct substitution_failure {};

 template<typename T>
 struct substitution_succeeded : std::true_type
 {};

 template<>
 struct substitution_succeeded<substitution_failure>:std::false_type
 {};

 template<typename T>
 struct get_f_result {
 private:
 template<typename X>
 static auto check(X const& x)->decltype(f(x));
 static substitution_failure check(...);
public:
using type = decltype(check(std::declval<T>()));
 };

template<typename T>
struct has_f:substitution_succeeded<typename get_f_result<T>::type>
{};


  template<typename T>
  constexpr bool Has_f() {
  return has_f<T>::value;
}


 template<typename T>
 class X {
public:
template<typename U=T>
 Enable_if<Has_f<U>()> use_f(const U& t) {
    f(t);
 }

  };


 int main()
{
std::cout << Has_f<Y>();
}
```

I know that this question is probable duplicate or triplicate or n-plicate on SO but I haven't found a convincing answer so I will re-post the question. Why the above code says that `Y` has **not**  an `f` function. I tried it using Visual Studio 2017 and GCC 7.3.0. I have also found a more simple code here in SO that works. But I cannot understand why this code does not work. The code that works follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
using namespace std;


 struct Hello
{
int helloworld() { return 0; }
};

 struct Generic {};

 // SFINAE test
template <typename T>
class has_helloworld
{
typedef char one;
typedef long two;

template <typename C> static one test(decltype(&C::helloworld));
template <typename C> static two test(...);

public:
enum { value = sizeof(test<T>(0)) == sizeof(char) };
};

int main() {

std::cout << has_helloworld<Hello>::value << std::endl;
std::cout << has_helloworld<Generic>::value << std::endl;
std::getchar();
return 0;
```

}

Comment: Compiles for me in GCC 8.1.x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stroustrup's code checks for a free function taking a single argument of that type. Your `Y` class instead has a member function.

That is, his code takes a type `T` and checks that calling `f(instance of T)` is well-formed. You can see this in `use_f`. Your code requires calling `(instance of T).f(instance of int)`.

Defining the `Y` class to work with the check being done [causes an output of 1](https://wandbox.org/permlink/DCR2hOIPsznHvQj0):

```
struct Y {};

void f(Y);
```

Alternatively, [change the check](https://wandbox.org/permlink/U9plAsYv1KcqA32h) to work with your class, taking care to change the `const` as well because your member function is non-const:

```
template<typename T>
struct get_f_result {
private:
    template<typename X>
    static auto check(X& x)->decltype(x.f(0));
    static substitution_failure check(...);
public:
   using type = decltype(check(std::declval<T&>()));
};
```